# Change the gray levels of pixels of an image

Tags: opencv, grayscale

In particular, I have 2 vectors that have been filled by integers between 0 and 255 and a gray scale image.
I want to change the gray level of pixels of the image that matches with vec1[i] to vec2[i].

Do you know any function or fast procedure that can perform this in OpenCV?

I couldnt find a built-in function that returns all pixels with a specified gray level in OpenCV.

Best
Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is known as a lookup-table transform, and that exists in opencv ([link to documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/STRAWMAN/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=lut#LUT)). You will have to adapt your input format a bit though .